# C++ How To Make A Templated Arguement?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I was watching a tutorial on how to do something as I came along a situation where I need to take in a various amount of parameters.

```
template<typename... Type>
bool Entity::hasAll() 
{
     std::cout << registry.all_of<Type...>(e);
     return false;
}
```

I want to know what the 3 dots mean, to my understanding they mean you can pass in any amount of parameters but than why must I have the 3 dots on this line "std::cout << registry.all_of<Type...>"(e); can someone eplain this please???

Comment: The title doesn't really match the body of the question... Do you want to understand the ellipsis or do you have something else on your mind?

Answer (score 3):

It's called `parameter_pack`. For further information, look at [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: An answer that's basically just a link isn't considered a good answer. This is a good comment. You could elaborate a bit, but I'd recommend just waiting until you can comment.